# Probability distribution function of data with fixed sum and interval constraints

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have generated the following 6 data sets from my original data set `a=[100,100,50,150,100]`

```
 [ 75 128  32 150 115]
 [ 78 141  60 112 109]
 [118  86  58 119 119]
 [ 94 146  56  89 115]
 [115  63  33 159 130]
 [113 111  47 111 118]
```

In each data set, the total sum remains same = 500. Moreover, each individual element in a single data set can vary between ± 50 % of the original value. For example, element 50 in the original set can only vary between 25 and 75.

I want to understand if there is any way to construct a joint sampling distribution for $a$

. I have looked into Dirichlet Distribution but was not sure if this fits.

Comment: It seems to be that each element of the new generated data will take a uniform distribution as $n_{i} \text{~} U(n_{i}-.5n_{i},n_{i}+.5n_{i}), i \in \{1,...,6\}$ where $n_{a}$ is independent of $n_{b}$ for all $a,b \in\{1,...,6\}$ such that $a\not=b$

Comment: @BayesIsBae Will this uniform distribution also take into account the total sum constrain?

Comment: oh sorry, it will not take into account the total sum restraint (I didn't see that, my bad).